# Why does my app.css doesn't include normalize.css

Tags: laravel-mix, tailwind-css

[image]
[image]

[image: app.scss]

Why does it doesn't include the normalize.css

Those are the modules that I've written, I hope somone can help me

[image]

Look at the margin there's its' a bit off.

Comment: Try adding semicolons after the `@tailwind` directives.

Comment: got your answer right

Comment: I have created an answer for this. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be because you haven't added semicolons (`;`) after the tailwind directives.

```
@tailwind preflight;
//                 ^
```